# Converting text to Datetime in specific format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I need an expression which will convert a text (`VARCHAR`) column to a `DATETIME` if, and only if, it matches `dd/MM/yyyy`, `d/MM/yyyy`, `dd/M/yyyy` or `d/M/yyyy`. If it doesn't match then I want a `NULL`.

I have this...

```
CASE ISDATE([DateField]) 
  WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME,[DateField],103) 
  ELSE NULL 
END
```

However this fails for `'15/04/76'` for example - with a "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string" error - whereas I would want it to return `NULL`

Example output

```
'1/6/1976'     -> 1976-06-01
'01/06/1976'   -> 1976-06-01
'13/06/2001'   -> 2001-06-13
'06/13/2001'   -> NULL
'13/06/76'     -> NULL
```

Is there a way of forcing `ISDATE` to validate a given format?

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) seems to suggest so...

> ISDATE is deterministic only if used with the CONVERT function, the
>   CONVERT style parameter is specified and style is not equal to 0, 100,
>   9, or 109.

But `ISDATE` only takes one argument, so how do I "use it with CONVERT function" if I am not doing so already?

Comment: Please leave comments when downvoting. This question is perfectly valid.

Comment: It's funny that I've received the 'Popular Question' badge for this question which has received one downvote and no upvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a nested case statement here.  The first could check to see if you have a 10 character string 2 for day, 2 for month, 4 for year and 2 for separators = 10 characters.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

    Case When DateField Like '%/%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
         Then Case When IsDate(DateField) = 1 
                   Then CONVERT(DATETIME,[DateField],103) 
                   End
         End
```

Revised:  I changed the code to use a like search which forces there to be a /YYYY at the end of the string, and then does an IsDate check to allow for a single day and/or month.

Comment: Hi I also need `1/6/1976` for example to be valid and converted to a DATETIME

Comment: Is the extra case really necessary? I think you could do this with a simple `AND`. Processing order should not change the result.

Comment: Aaron.  I believe you are correct.  If you replace the nested case with the AND keyword, our solutions are virtually identical.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, why on earth are you storing datetime values in a varchar column? This is a cardinal sin for a variety of reasons, not the least of which is that you get no validation whatsoever that the data is (or is convertible to) a datetime. You should also consider validating the input, even if you leave the column as varchar, so you don't have such a wide variety of potential formats that you want to consider valid.

So here is one way, borrowing a bit from @G Mastros:

```
DECLARE @f TABLE(i INT, d VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @f VALUES
(1,'15/04/76'),
(2,'15/04/1976'),
(3,'1/3/1976'),
(4,'1/3/76'),
(5,'15/3/1976'),
(6,'22/22/22'),
(7,'Yesterday');

SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT i, d, d2 = CASE WHEN ISDATE(d) = 1
    AND d LIKE '%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, d, 103) END
  FROM @f;
```

Results:

```
i  d           d2
-  ----------  -----------------------
1  15/04/76    NULL
2  15/04/1976  1976-04-15 00:00:00.000
3  1/3/1976    1976-03-01 00:00:00.000
4  1/3/76      NULL
5  15/3/1976   1976-03-15 00:00:00.000
6  22/22/22    NULL
7  Yesterday   NULL
```

PS this will be a great case for [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) in SQL Server 2012. It does exactly what you're asking - it tries to convert to the specified data type; if it can't, it returns `NULL`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP requires 4 digits for the year.  If there are only 2 digits for the year, the OP wants NULL.  Your code does not handle that.

Comment: Sorry, missed that requirement. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the light beration but unfortunately the schema I am working with is not of my devising (and would not be this way were it so). I am also not responsible for the validation of data going into it. Answer looks good thanks, I'll give it a go :)

Comment: It yields `NULL` for `06/13/2001` and a proper date value for `13/06/2001`. I highly recommend you pass along some idea of how bad this design is to the people that are responsible for the schema and data validation. This won't be the last problem they'll have with this.

Comment: @Aaron Don't worry I'm very vocal about what a pig this schema is :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses folks.

I've done it like this...

```
CASE ISDATE([DateField]) WHEN 1 THEN 
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([DateField],LEN([DateField])-4,1) = '/' THEN
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',[DateField],LEN([DateField])-3)=0 THEN
            CONVERT(datetime, [DateField] , 103) 
        END
    END
END
```

which is pretty nasty business so would still appreciate something neater!

**But this doesn't work either - it still errors on mm/dd/yyyy format dates!**

Scrap that last comment - it does seem to work now? Probably something to do with `SET DATEFORMAT`

Comment: Your code fails if the string is not a valid date.  For example, run your code against the string 'Yesterday', and you will get a conversion error.

Comment: You're putting a datetime value into a varchar. How do you expect SQL Server to tell the difference between `01/03/1976` and `03/01/1976`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm aware how stupid it is to put dates in a text field (not my database...). However I only want to work with dd/MM/yyyy dates - therefore I was hoping there might be a function similar to .Net's `TryParseExact`. Thanks for your `TRY_CONVERT` suggestion - I look forward to getting 2012!

Comment: @El Ronnoco, I apologize, but as you mentioned, it errors depending on your data.  Have you looked at my revised suggestion?